# How to draw a button using winAPI

Tags: c, windows, winapi, button, ownerdrawn

I have successfully created an owner drawn button.

But how do I now draw/color the darn thing, to make it look like a Button using the Windows API? Currently, it just looks like a colored label?

Any C examples?

Comment: Curious why you are doing this in the first place? The usual reason for creating an owner-draw control is because you don't want it to look like a standard control. But if you want this to look like a standard button, then why not just use a standard button?

Comment: "Curious why you are doing this in the first place?": (Windows7) The end language that i'll be using (HotBasic) doesnt facilitate this .color and .textColor for BUTTONs. So I need to get into API to make them pretty. I can read "C" code and then translate it into HotBasic. Thanks...Vernon

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for [DrawFrameControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162480%28VS.85%29.aspx). For the cool, Vista/7-looking controls, look at `uxtheme.dll`.

Comment: Ok, will check back after a while. Thanks...Vernon

Comment: Chnage look or color in my answer

Answer (score 1):

For the modern-looking buttons, just copy/paste this into your source:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

Well, unless you want to memorize it...